# Using a lot of libraries in Web App

Tags: jquery, performance, twitter-bootstrap, web-applications

I am new to Web App Development.
I noticed that a lot of libraries had to be included in the application just to make things easier. I am talking about javascript libraries like jquery, bootstrap, jqueryUI and css libraries like bootstrap etc.

Now I also found that two kind of downloads existed for jQuery one was the full version and the other one was min.js, which I am using.
For that, I read somewhere (can't remember where) that once in production, it's a good idea to have min.js because it will make the app be faster.

So the question came to my mind is it a trade-off ?

Is the number of libraries I am including in my web app going to affect its performance in production ?

Comment: Yes. Longer loading, longer processing, increased memory usage... Only "use" what you need to use. Also, look here [MicroJS](http://microjs.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now I also found that two kind of downloads existed for jQuery one was
>   the full version and the other one was min.js, which I am using. For
>   that, I read somewhere (can't remember where) that once in production,
>   it's a good idea to have min.js because it will make the app be
>   faster.

The min.js one is the minified version of the full version. Grossly simplifying it removes redundant spaces and characters, shortens your variable names, etc. to **reduce the size of your js file**.

*Unless you are on a really fast network* (think Intranet / local html files), minification speeds up your js file download. *If your js file* is a render blocking resource, this means your page will render faster.

https://developers.google.com/speed/ provides and excellent set of tools to optimize your site for speed. https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/rules has the rules and explanation

> So the question came to my mind is it a trade-off ?

In a way yes, it is a trade off between smaller files (i.e. faster site downloads) and readability (you can't easily make sense of a minified file) / build complexity (most applications would include a build step where development non-minified versions of script files are swapped out with their minified / concatenated versions for production.

However with source maps (see http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/) and IDE plugins / good build tools this is becoming a very low overhead thing.

> Is the number of libraries I am including in my web app going to
>   affect its performance in production ?

Yes, it is. Download times and script execution times are going to affect both perceived (how quickly a user can start using the page) and actual performance (more script = more resources, though this is not much of a problem).

You could lazy load your scripts (e.g. requirejs.org/), optimize your library file to exclude things you don't need (e.g. http://getbootstrap.com/customize/, http://jqueryui.com/download/), use a CDN (see http://gtmetrix.com/why-use-a-cdn.html), make sure you set your script to cache, etc.

---

This is by no means comprehensive list, but a word of advice. When it comes to performance, it's best (and fruitful) to **measure first** and then figure out what you want to optimize based on what is causing (perceived or actual) performance problems.

[Here](http://miniprofiler.com/) is one such tool used on data.stackexchange, but there are many others.

---

tldr; yes